# NSIS v3.08 and nsUnzip

Tags: installation, compression, nsis

I am trying to use the NsUnzip plugin with v3.08 of NSIS, but I keep getting a result code of 9 on all calls used in the "nsUnzipTest.nsi" when I use v3.08.  I added the DLL file to both the "z86-ansi" and "x86-unicode" folders.  I even tried adding the "Unicode true" to the NSI script, and it still gave a result code of 9.  Since a code of 9 is "The specified zipfile(s) was not found", I went ahead and added a FileOpen and FileClose using the same path.  FileOpen worked fine.

I changed back to NSIS 2.46 and the plugin worked without issue.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like that plug-in supports Unicode. In NSIS 3 you would have to add `Unicode False` to the top of your .nsi.

You could try re-compiling the plug-in yourself or try contacting the author...